# Error publishing to Azure cloud service with osFamily=5

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-powershell

I am trying to update a cloud service to use .NET 4.6. I changing the osFamily="4" to osFamily="5" in the .cscfg file as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix

Looking at my file system I have this SDK version installed:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9

Looking at Web PI, I have these installed:

- VS Community 2105 with Azure SDK - 2.9.6
- VS Community 2105 with Azure SDK - 3.0
- Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2015) - 2.9.6
- Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2015) - 3.0

I normally use Powershell cmdlets to deploy using New-AzureDeployment/Set-AzureDeployment from a build & deployment server. I will occasionally deploy from my desktop using powershell for testing.

If I leave the osFamily="4" unchanged and deploy with Powershell everything works as expected.

If I use VS2015 and the Publish Azure Application tool to do the deployment it succeeds as expected if I choose either osFamily="4" or osFamily="5".

Checking which module is used:

```
C:\> (Get-Command Set-AzureDeployment).Module.Path
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Azure\3.8.0\Azure.psm1
```

Running the deployment Set-AzureDeployment (given an existing package has been deployed) gives me the following error -

```
Set-AzureDeployment : BadRequest : The OS family 5 you are trying to deploy is not supported by the SDK package. The SDK package supported OS families:3,4,1,2,98. Please try to deploy to a different operating system. To do this specify a different osFamily and/or osVersion in your .cscfg file.
```

I don't see which SDK "package" the commandlet is complaining about...any ideas?

Comment: You have to create the cspkg with the new SDK as well. Did you?

Comment: @MartinBrandl It must not be built with the SDK v2.9. I will look and see if we are hard coding the SDK version in our build steps.

Comment: I read about the same error where the solution was to build the package with the new sdk.

Comment: Does New-AzureDeployment behave any differently?

Comment: @bmoore-msft I'm not sure what you mean by behave differently. I think martin-brandl is closer to the issue. I need to understand how my MSBUILD based packaging step decides which SDK to use...

Comment: Hm. I've just hit this same error with a build from our CI server which logged that it was produced with "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\cspack.exe" and supposedly MSBuild from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\" for some parts of build, but in actually it seems to be using C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin for building the .ccproj

Comment: We have both VS2013 and VS2015 on the machine where it was built, but on another machine built with just VS2017 and it worked great, sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a newer version of the *2.9* Azure Authoring Tools.

I reproduced this problem with Azure Authoring Tools 2.9.1, but remedied it by upgrading to version 2.9.5.3. Actually it's mentioned as fixed in the [release notes](https://aka.ms/azuresdk_rn_300) for Azure '3.0' SDK [(download link)](https://aka.ms/azuresdk_dlc_300):

> Visual Studio now supports deploying Cloud Services to OS Family 5
>   (Windows Server 2016) virtual machines. For existing cloud services,
>   you can change your settings to target the new OS Family. When
>   creating new cloud services, if you choose to create the service using
>   .net 4.6 or higher, it will default the service to use OS Family 5.
>   For more information, you can review the Guest OS Family support
>   table.